# Force Xamarin Studio view layout to stay the same

Tags: layout, xamarin, ide, xamarin-studio

I'm currently using Xamarin Studio and have a comfortable enough setup so that I can put my various pads (output, unit tests, solution tree, etc.) on different screens. I like it and I'd like it to stay the same wether I'm debugging, running tests or coding.

But right now, xamarin studio handles it himself and switches to the Debug view layout when debugging, which changes everything to their default (since I've never really changed it).

Is it possible to tell Xamarin Studio to either :
- Never switch layouts?
- Set which layout is used for each situation (and I would just use my custom layout)

I've tried deleting all layouts and XS just recreates them. No dice here.
I've tried switching to my layout when debugging, hoping it would remember "this is my debug layout now". No chance either.

And I'm hoping I won't have to change each separate layout, because first it'll take a stupid amount of time, and also because if I ever decide to make a change, i'd have to set it up over 5 different view layouts which is just ridiculous.

Note : I'm using the latest version of Xamarin of the stable channel.

So, does anyone know a way to keep one single layout for all situations?

Comment: Thanks for the blind downvote, very constructive of you

Comment: Did you consider creating a [custom layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/customizing-ide/#Workspace_Layout)? Then, when you're debugging, you should be able to choose this custom layout. This would also mean that you could avoid having to update several different layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, it is not possible with the current version of Xamarin Studio.

I read through both the preferences as well as the documentation. I even tried to [create my own custom layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/customizing-ide/#Workspace_Layout) by navigating to "View" -> "Save Current Layout". Then I selected my new custom layout when I started a debugging session, hoping it would persist to the next one. But alas, the "Debug" view was chosen automatically.

This would probably be something you could bring forth as a suggestion of improvement to the Xamarin team. You can do so using their [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).